# Making images editable in Magnolia

Tags: magnolia

I am creating templates using magnolia. I want to give the option for editing the images. Using magnolia 5.4 i am creating the templates. For editing the images in my page i created the area. My code is as follows:

```
templateScript: /hello-magnolia/templates/pages/hello.ftl
renderType: freemarker
visible: true
title: Hello
dialog: hello-magnolia:pages/hello
areas:
   main:
   renderType: freemarker
   availableComponents:
      quotation:
      id: hello-magnolia:components/quotation
      textImage:
      id: hello-magnolia:components/txtimg
```

txtimg.yaml:

```
   form:
    tabs:
     - name: tabImage
       label: Image
     fields:
       - name: upload
         class: info.magnolia.dam.app.ui.field.definition.DamUploadFieldDefinition
         label: Upload
   actions:
   commit:
       class:     info.magnolia.ui.admincentral.dialog.action.SaveDialogActionDefinition
   cancel:
       class: info.magnolia.ui.admincentral.dialog.action.CancelDialogActionDefinition
```

When i test this code my page is not loading. When i remove the last two lines then it is loading correctly. I  defined the correct path and also form definition and field definition for the image.

How i have to make my images editable using jsp.

Also how i can check  the condition for whether the image is available or not.

Can anyone help me in this

Comment: Do you get any error message in log, when you add these two last lines? And what does _editable images_ actually mean?

Comment: can you post definition of txtimg component as well? Are you sure it's not txtImg instead?

Comment: i added txtimg component definition @Jan

Answer (score 0):

The indentation of commit and cancel actions in texting.yaml is incorrect. It also looks like you might have erroneous tab before class name of commit action. Definition is in yaml format so it is rather sensitive to indentation.